# python: mean of variable length 2 matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Consider the following variable length 2D array

```
[
[1, 2, 3],
[4, 5],
[6, 7, 8, 9]
]
```

How can i find the mean of the variables along the column?

I want something like `[(1+4+6)/3,(2+5+7)/3, (3+8)/2, 9/1]`

So the end result would be `[3.667, 4.667, 5.5, 9]`

Is this possible using numpy?

I tried `np.mean(x, axis=0)`, but numpy expects the arrays of same dimension.

Right now, I am popping the elements of each column and finding the mean. Is there a better way to achieve the result?

Answer (score 5):

You could use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

a = [[1, 2, 3],
     [4, 5],
     [6, 7, 8, 9]]

df = pd.DataFrame(a)
# 0  1   2   3
# 0  1  2   3 NaN
# 1  4  5 NaN NaN
# 2  6  7   8   9

df.mean()
# 0    3.666667
# 1    4.666667
# 2    5.500000
# 3    9.000000
# dtype: float64
```

Here is another solution that only uses numpy:

```
import numpy as np
nrows = len(a)
ncols = max(len(row) for row in a)
arr = np.zeros((nrows, ncols))
arr.fill(np.nan)
for jrow, row in enumerate(a):
    for jcol, col in enumerate(row):
        arr[jrow, jcol] = col
print np.nanmean(arr, axis=0)
# array([ 3.66666667,  4.66666667,  5.5       ,  9.        ])
```

Answer (score 2):

Listed in this post is an almost vectorized approach using NumPy. We would try to assign  each element in list element an ID based on their positions. These IDs could then be fed to [`np.bincount`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) as it would perform ID based summations. Finally, we would divide the summations respectively by the lengths of each ID to get the final average values.

Thus, we would have an implementation like so -

```
def variable_mean(a):
    vals = np.concatenate(a)
    lens = np.array(map(len,a))
    id_arr = np.ones(vals.size,dtype=int)
    id_arr[0] = 0
    id_arr[lens.cumsum()[:-1]] = -lens[:-1] + 1
    IDs = id_arr.cumsum()
    return np.bincount(IDs,vals)/np.bincount(IDs)
```

Runtime test -

```
In [298]: # Setup input 
     ...: N = 1000 # number of elems in input list
     ...: minL = 3 # min len of an element (list) in input list
     ...: maxL = 10 # max len of an element (list) in input list
     ...: a = [list(np.random.randint(0,9,(i))) \
     ...:       for i in np.random.randint(minL,maxL,(N))]
     ...: 

In [299]: %timeit pd.DataFrame(a).mean() #@Julien Spronck's pandas soln
100 loops, best of 3: 3.33 ms per loop

In [300]: %timeit variable_mean(a)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.36 ms per loop

In [301]: # Setup input 
     ...: N = 1000 # number of elems in input list
     ...: minL = 3 # min len of an element (list) in input list
     ...: maxL = 100 # max len of an element (list) in input list
     ...: a = [list(np.random.randint(0,9,(i))) \
     ...:       for i in np.random.randint(minL,maxL,(N))]
     ...: 

In [302]: %timeit pd.DataFrame(a).mean() #@Julien Spronck's pandas soln
10 loops, best of 3: 27.1 ms per loop

In [303]: %timeit variable_mean(a)
100 loops, best of 3: 9.58 ms per loop
```

Comment: This should be called Numpythonic ;-).

Comment: @Kasramvd Haha well that's what I do mostly ;)

Answer (score 2):

Very simple alternative approach using [`itertools.izip_longest()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) as:

```
>>> mean_list = []
>>> for sub_list in izip_longest(*my_list):
...     filtered_list = filter(None, sub_list)
...     mean_list.append(sum(filtered_list)/(len(filtered_list)*1.0))
...
>>> mean_list
[3.6666666666666665, 4.666666666666667, 5.5, 9.0]
```

where `my_list` equals to:

```
[
[1, 2, 3],
[4, 5],
[6, 7, 8, 9]
]
```

Comment: Using 0 as a fill value ruins the average.

Comment: @TemporalWolf Ohh Yes. Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it manually, what I would do:

```
max_length = 0
```

Figure out the max array length:

```
for array in arrays:
    if len(array) > max:
        max = len(array)
```

Pad all arrays to that length with `'None'`

```
for array in arrays:
    while len(array) < max:
        array.append(None)
```

Zip will group the columns

```
columns = zip(*arrays)
```

`columns == [(1, 4, 6), (2, 5, 7), (3, 'None', 8), ('None', 'None', 9)]`

Calculate the average as you would for any list:

```
for col in columns:
    count = 0
    sum = 0.0
    for num in col:
        if num is not None:
            count += 1
            sum += float(num)
    print "%s: Avg %s" % (col, sum/count)
```

Or as a list comprehension after padding the arrays:

```
[sum(filter(None, col))/float(len(filter(None, col))) for col in zip(*arrays)]
```

Output:

```
(1, 4, 6): Avg 3.66666666667
(2, 5, 7): Avg 4.66666666667
(3, 'None', 8): Avg 5.5
('None', 'None', 9): Avg 9.0
```

Answer (score 0):

In Py3, `zip_longest` takes a `fillvalue` parameter:

```
In [1208]: ll=[
      ...: [1, 2, 3],
      ...: [4, 5],
      ...: [6, 7, 8, 9]
      ...: ]   
In [1209]: list(itertools.zip_longest(*ll, fillvalue=np.nan))
Out[1209]: [(1, 4, 6), (2, 5, 7), (3, nan, 8), (nan, nan, 9)]
```

By filling with `nan`, I can use `np.nanmean` to take the mean ignoring the `nan`.  `nanmean` turns its input (here `_` from the previous line) into an array:

```
In [1210]: np.nanmean(_, axis=1)
Out[1210]: array([ 3.66666667,  4.66666667,  5.5       ,  9.        ])
```